# For loop exit condition with map iterator

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, stdmap, std

I have a `std::map<str,int> my_map`

Right now, the key-value mapping looks like this -

```
{["apple",3],["addition",2],["app",7],["adapt",8]}
```

**Objective**:

Calculate the sum of values of keys with a given prefix.
Example : `sum("ap")` should return `10 (3 + 7)`.

I could implement it with two loops and an if condition. But, I'm trying to understand the following code that's submitted by someone to implement this.

```
for (auto it = my_map.lower_bound(prefix); 
    it != my_map.end() && it->first.substr(0, n) == prefix;
    it++)
```

Won't the loop condition become false in the middle of iterating through `my_map` hence calculating an incorrect sum ?

I don't know how the code is able to give the right result. Why wouldn't the loop exit when it gets to key "`addition`" while looking for prefix "`ap`" ?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: What would make the loop condition "false" at an incorrect iteration point ? The *starting* iterator is from lower_bound. that's probably worth a look.

Comment: @JeJo The second condition will be false for key "`addition`" right ? So the loop should exit ? Am I missing something

Comment: @WhozCraig Key "`addition`" is the incorrect iteration point where the condition becomes false.

Comment: What you may be missing is that a `map` is always sorted.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, Oh alright. So essentially, the iterator won't get to "`addition`" at all as the lower_bound is "`ap`" ? It will start from "`ap`", get to "`apple`" and the loop exits as it gets to `it.end()` ?

Comment: @JnRambo Looks to me like that is what will happen. But imagine other cases like searching for `"ad"`.  Then, it'll find an element that doesn't start with `"ad"` before it reaches `end()`. In that case the other half of the condition comes into play. But this code is trying to be clever. It does not clearly express the intention, it makes you think to figure out what it does. It should be simplified or documented.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, Yeah saw this solution on a weekly contest. A bit tricky at first sight yet efficient. Thanks for the help btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop is completely correct, but not so readable at first sight.

We have `std::map` which is an associative container and sorted according to the compare function provided. For your map (i.e `std::map<std:.string, int>`), it will be sorted according to the `std::string` (i.e key).

So your map is already ordered like :

```
{["adapt",8], ["addition",2], ....., ["app",7], ["apple",3], .... }
```

Now let's start with the [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound):

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range **[first,
> Last) that is not less than (i.e. greater or equal to) value, or last
> if no such element is found**.

Meaning at the loop start:

```
auto it = my_map.lower_bound(prefix);
```

iterator `it` is pointing to the map entry `["app",7]`. In otherwards the iteration starts from the first possible start.

```
["app",7], ["apple",3], ....
```

Now the condition comes in to play:

```
it != my_map.end() && it->first.substr(0, n) == prefix;
```

The first one to see whether the iterator is valid (i.e. `it != my_map.end()`).
The second one checks whether the prefix is the same as the key start (i.e. `it->first.substr(0, n) == prefix;`). Since we start from the sorted possible prefix start, the outcome of the loop will be correct.